# When I wanted use Http library on vscode . I got that notice :Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: http, flutter, visual-studio-code

**I wanted import Http library on Dart. But,I'm getting the error when I run the flutter get packages on VScode.**

> This is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: flutter_first_app
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    http: 0.12.0 
 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

***The Error is***

> Error on line 13, column 2: Expected a key while parsing a block
>   mapping.    ╷ 13 │  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2    │  ^    ╵ Please
>   correct the pubspec.yaml file at
>   F:\flutterprojects\flutter_first_app\pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was **re-edited** my pubspec.yaml file ***as below*** in this way the issue was fixed.

```
name: flutter_first_app
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0 
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one space before the following in line your pubspec.yaml

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

Every space in pubspec.yaml file gets counted and important to manage.

Comment: And if you don't like counting spaces, keep in mind that JSON is also proper YAML, so you could have written that dependency clause as: {dependencies: flutter: {sdk: flutter}, http: "0.12.0", cupertino_icons:"^0.1.2"
} and it would just work (no need to quote most keys too)